# ngOnInit triggered twice because of double routing config

Tags: angular

My routing looks like this:

```
{
    path: 'menu/:level/:parent', component: MenuComponent, pathMatch : 'full'
},
{
    path: 'menu', component: MenuComponent,
},
```

What I want to achieve is if I have the url `menu/2/test` to use the first route and if I have only menu to use the second route.

At the moment I can see that `ngOnInit` is triggered twice for url `menu/2/test`, which I want to avoid.

Can someone advice how these routes should look like, so if it matches first route it doesn't look further?

Comment: it could be not a problem with routing, please add more file so that people can check your issue more carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacked up a quick example in stackBlitz.

It behaves accordingly, See if you are doing anything different

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yvmt9f

Comment: Great, that is it! The problem was since I didn't have `pathMatch: 'full'` on both routes under `menu`